# Find records with multible column name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have table `Offer` who have one `OfferDescription` dependence with activities stores like this:

```
t.boolean "discovery", default: false
t.boolean "meeting_animals", default: false
t.boolean "milking_animals", default: false
t.boolean "tasting", default: false
t.boolean "birth_animal", default: false
t.boolean "stroll", default: false
t.boolean "harvest", default: false
t.boolean "craft", default: false
```

My users can search Offers by activities, its ok when they select only one activity i did the request like this

```
activity = params[:activity].gsub(/'/, '')

.joins(:address, :offer_description)
.where("max_people_count >= ? AND offer_descriptions.#{activity}=?", peopleCount, true)
.near(location, distance, unit: :km)
```

But how i can do properly when they select multiple activities to find Offers who have this activity OR another one ?

The way the `OfferDescription` table was made look little bit strange for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be

I assume for multiple activities we will get it in an array.

```
activities = ['discovery', 'meeting_animals']
activity_query = activities.each_with_object([]).do |activity, query|
  query << "offer_descriptions.#{activity} = :flag"
end.join(" OR ")

.joins(:address, :offer_description)
.where("max_people_count >= ? AND " + activity_query, 
       peopleCount, flag: true)
.near(location, distance, unit: :km)
```